# Is there a way that a browser (Chrome) plugin could see what .js's are loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just want to see other implementations of a .js and would like to write a Chrome plugin that would tell me when a site is using WRd.js. Is there a way I can do that?  even better is there already a plugin that does do that?

Comment: [Try Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/), or [Direct link on chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/ghostery?hl=en-US).